# Is there a reason to have more than one reactiveValues()?

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a difference between

```
values <- reactiveValues()

observe({
invalidateLater(1,session)
values$data_1 = ... #do some calculation
values$data_2 = ... #do some calculation
})
```

and

```
values1 <- reactiveValues()
values2 <- reactiveValues()    
observe({
invalidateLater(1,session)
values1$data_1 = ... #do some calculation
values2$data_2 = ... #do some calculation
})
```

Is there a reason why you wouldn't combine all your data storage into just one `reactiveValues()` expression?

Comment: Good question. I cant think explicitly why you would need more than one apart from bookkeeping and perhaps code clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment in general you would only have one `reactiveValues` unless you wanted more for bookkeeping etc. However it maybe the case that you want two `reactiveValues`
The first `reactiveValues` is declared globally in say for example `global.R` or outside `shinyServer`. This `reactiveValues` handles stored values across users. The second `reactiveValues` would be declared within `shinyServer`. This `reactiveValues` would be for storing values for a users particular session.